# How to only add values that end with 's'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to do this but I know this isn't the right syntax:

```
INSERT INTO TBL1
SELECT Col1    
FROM TBL2    
WHERE Col1.endswith('s')
```

Comment: and annother one, if on ms-sql server:

Comment: where reverse(col1) like 'S%'

or

where left(reverse(col1), 1) = 's'

Comment: @Ice: No need for `REVERSE()` here

Comment: Yes, not really nesesary but it is one possibility of many.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TBL1
SELECT Col1    
FROM TBL2    
WHERE col1 LIKE '%s'
```

where `%` works like `*` in wildcard and `.*` in RegEx. It is SQL Server RegEx pattern indeed.

Comment: @wil: Thank you! btw, what does it mean, if not a secret? :)

Comment: Hammen Akhen? It basically means 'here ya go'

Comment: It is equivalent to the regex `.*` for 0 or more charactors. Not `.+` which is of course 1 more charactor.  But I'm sure you knew that really.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO TBL1 
SELECT Col1
FROM TBL2
WHERE Col1 LIKE '%s'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Insert Into TBL1
select Col1
from TBL2
where Col1 like '%s'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE col1 like '%s'
```

% is the wildcard character which takes any value or any number of characters.

This site is good for learning this kind of thing: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correction to the where clause of your insert statement:

```
where substring(col1,LEN(col1)-1,1) = 's'
```

Here is your complete insert statement with the corrected where clause:

```
INSERT INTO TBL1
SELECT Col1    
FROM TBL2    
WHERE where substring(col1,LEN(col1)-1,1) = 's'
```